# what are the compression forces in a strut if the strut is fixed

Tags: wing

i am trying to match an experiment i have done and i dont know how to compute the force in the strut in terms of F given these boundary conditions. i have attempted to use fixed end moment equations but cant find anything suitable, can anyone help as to why this might not work or how it might work?[image]

Comment: This looks a lot more like general engineering than about Aviation. Note that on the ground, the weight of the wing is the net down-force, but in flight, the wing is lifting with enough force to equal not just the weight of the wing but the weight of the entire aircraft (distributed over both wings), so the strut would no longer experience compression, but tension.

Comment: F will actually be located at the spanwise center of lift, in the up direction, somewhere just inboard of mid span. If you place the strut attachment at a sweet spot, which depends on the elasticity of the wing spar, you can arrange it so the load on with wing root is reduced to zero in the vertical axis with only a lateral compression load. The vast majority of the lift is being borne by the strut in tension. The 3 attachments are always pin joints. On a Twin Otter, which has a lot more span outboard than inboard of the attachment, the load on the wing root fitting is DOWN plus compression.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni where did you get the 2F from?

Comment: @mwtb123 from F at the wing tip.  The actual load may be distributed across the entire wing, resulting in most of being supported by the strut (as 1F).  See JohnK comment above for the (excellent) real world story.

Comment: Is the wing-"strut" connection a hinge or fixed?

Comment: That would indeed be the common way of doing it Robert. However, the question specifically states that the strut is fixed (not a pin joint!) at the bottom left. So then it's no longer safe to assume that the connection at the wing is also a pin joint...

Comment: [This link](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mFkc-7Fd0QQ) should help.

Comment: In terms of movement (whether pinned or welded) the strut *is* more or less fixed.  *Slight* movement (repeatedly) could cause fatigue in a weld.

Answer (score 1):

The practical answer is that, unless your connection with the "wall" is extremely rigid *and* the "strut" is extremely stiff in bending, the situation can be reasonably well approximated by a pin-jointed strut. However, assuming you really want to know the answer, you'll have to resort to methods for statically indeterminate problems.

For the problem as presented I see no easy shortcut so you'll have to rely on general methods. I would recommend the method of virtual displacements. At the connection point, determine the resulting forces and moment for a virtual displacement dx and dy and rotation drz. Do this for both the strut and the left hand side of the wing. The strut will have longitudinal stiffness and bending stiffness due to a end force and moment load. Easy enough to calculate in the strut frame of reference, and afterwards just decompose the resulting forces in the global frame of reference (moments are unchanged). The left side of the wing has longitudinal stiffness and bending stiffness due to a moment load.

Add up all the forces with each virtual displacement. Equate with the force and moment due to the force at the hinge point. That gives you the actual displacements. Finally, from these displacements calculate back the force at the strut. Basically you've done a FEM analysis by hand.

Now redo the analysis for the much simpler pin jointed strut and realise you've gone through a lot of effort for a marginal difference in results. Note that the strut is not infinitely rigidly attached at the wall (quite the opposite typically) so even this small difference disappears.